# Копирование файлов в Linux при их перезаписи

Tags: linux, shell, резервное-копирование

Знаю, что есть вероятность копирования данных во время их перезаписи (например, при регулярном бэкапе). Хочу узнать, может ли произойти такое что скопированные данные будут повреждены или не будут скопированны вообще в таком случае. Если да, то как это можно предотвратить?
Для бэкапа использую команду "cp"

Comment: Не понял, а что Вы копируете командой *cp* во время бэкапа? Если исходные файлы, то они никакими известными мне программами бэкапа НЕ изменяются. А если целевые файлы, там где создаётся бэкап, то зачем их копировать во время бэкапа?!

Comment: Sergey, извините, не уточнил. Я делаю бэкап используя "cp", а не использую "cp" во время бэкапа

Comment: Проведи тестирование

Comment: Можно создавать Snapshot фс.

Comment: Да, файлы могут быть повреждены (которые в бекапе). Для важных приложений, вроде баз данных используйте их средства бекапа. В остальных услучаях лучше использовать утилиты backup/restore из комплекта утилит вашей файловой системы

Comment: При таком подходе данные в бэкапе могут быть не повреждены, а *логически неконсистентны* (впрочем, скорее всего вы имели в виду именно это). Для предотвращения нужно принять организационные меры, которые предотвратят запуск во время бэкапа процессов, изменяющих копируемые файлы

Comment: Выучите замечательную команду *rsync*.

Comment: Да, проблема такая есть при любом способе бэкапа - если во время выполнения процедуры копируемые данные подвергаются изменениям. Если эти данные как-то структурно связаны, то это может сделать бэкап совершенно бессмысленным.

Простейший способ - заблокировать доступ на время бэкапа.  Крайний вариант - демонтировать файловую систему.

Comment: @0andriy rsync блокирует файл на запись?)

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб предотвратить изменение файла во время копирования лучше воспользоватья Снапшотами.

Например у меня установка на lvm.

```
#!/bin/bash

lvcreate -L1G -s -n back-bases /dev/lghost/bases
mkdir -p /backup/source
mount -o ro,offset=1048576 /dev/lghost/back-bases /backup/source
cd /backup/
find ./source/basedir/ -iname '*.DBF' | tar czf basedir-`date +%F`.tar.gz --files-from=-
umount /backup/source
lvremove -f /dev/lghost/back-bases
```

Этим скриптом делаю снимок раздела диска, монтирую его в отдельную папку, достаю файлы и удаляю снимок.

`-L1G` значит что один гигабайт может быть записан в основной раздел не повреждая снимок.

`,offset=1048576` - там ещё сигнатура mbr у меня. Вам скорее всего без смещения нужно.

При таком бакупе возможно появление файлов с недописанными данными, середина транзакции и тому подобное. Например программа вытерла кусок в базе данных для изменения, но не успела перезаписать туда транзакцию. Я пишу бакупы ночью чтоб минимизировать такие риски.